# Extract File Name from Shared library

Tags: c++, linux

is it possible to get file name/function name from shared library or binary.I need to debug the shared library but not able to determine the file name from shared library

Comment: Was the library built with debug information?

Comment: What filename are we talking about? Source code, or the shared library?>

Comment: Yes it is built with debug symbol.

Comment: @Mat,I came to know we can not extract source code from shared library .So I am looking for file level information( file name or function name). So that I can reach file or function and do the code walk through

Comment: Source code is only available if you compiled the library (or know where the source code is) and connecting the two together (e.g. this is line 83 in foo.c) is only available if you have debug information. Function names are given in libraries tho' - `nm mylib.so` will show you the name of all external symbols.